# ¿El operador condicional ? de c# sólo puede usarse con números?

Tags: visual-studio

Quería agregar a mí código el operador condicional "?", en los ejemplos que he visto siempre puede asignar un valor dependiendo de la condición, pero lo intenté usar comparando un booleano y un string para darle un valor a una cadena y me dio error.

Lo que quiero hacer, es recibir los elementos a insertar en una base de datos y por medio de comparaciones ver el tipo que posee cada campo para así poder agregarlo a la sentencia en el formato correcto, pero como quería acortar un poco el código traté de usar el condicional ?. Como pueden ver, comenté los if para probar, por eso quería preguntarles si era posible, ya que de no ser así, pues seguiré usando los if que tenía.

Este es mi código:

```
public string crear_sentencia(string nombre_tabla, List<string>datos, int cantidad_Datos) {

            string sentencia = "insert into " + nombre_tabla + " values(";
            int contador = 0, ent = 0;
            double dec = 0;
            foreach (string dato in datos)
            {
                sentencia += dato;
                bool tipoDato = int.TryParse(dato, out ent) || double.TryParse(dato, out dec);
                tipoDato = true ? sentencia+= dato: sentencia+="'"+dato+"'";
                contador < cantidad_Datos ? sentencia += "," : sentencia += ");";
               /* if (contador < cantidad_Datos)
                { 
                    sentencia += ",";
                }else
                {
                    sentencia += ");";
                }
                contador++;*/
            }
            MessageBox.Show(cantidad_Datos.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(sentencia);
        }

    }
```

Y estos son los errores que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que usas mal el operador ternario, así a ojo diría que es:
sentencia = contador < cantidad_Datos ? sentencia + "," : sentencia + ");";

Comment: Encapsula las asignaciones dentro de paréntesis del modo `condicion ? (asignacion 1) : (asignacion 2)`. Algo que no me queda claro es lo que quieres hacer en la línea de asignación de `tipoDato` ya que tienes true y eso ocasionará que siempre tome el primer camino, pero aparte luego ya no haces nada con esa variable.

Comment: Una recomendación: el propósito del código que muestras parece ser armar una sentencia de inserción de SQL .  La manera en la que lo estás haciendo se presta para un ataque de [inyección de sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), sobre todo si los valores que están almacenados en `datos` provienen del usuario. Es muy recomendable utilizar la clase `System.Data.Common.DbParameter` para prevenir este tipo de ataques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que usas mal el operador ternario.
El orden es:
variable_a_inicializar = operacion_booleana ? valor_si_true : valor_si_false; 
Así que a ojo, creo que lo que quieres hacer se parece a:

```
sentencia = contador < cantidad_Datos ? sentencia + "," : sentencia + ");";
```

Comment: Gracias! Tienes razón, estaba usando mal el operador ternario! Muchas gracias!

Comment: ojo.. seria mucho mejor y mas lindo hacer sentencia += contador < cantidad_Datos ? "," : ");"; de esa forma solo se agrega a sentencia una sola vez, si no estas reconstruyendo el string dos veces

Answer (score 2):

Primero, la teoría:

## Operador condicional ternario

Lo que tu quieres utilizar se llama [operador condicional ternario](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) y es una expresión que tiene la forma:

```
expresionBool ? expresionSiVerdadero : expresionSiFalso;
```

Para calcular el valor que devolverá el operador, se evalúa la primera expresión `expresionBool`, que debe devolver un valor booleano (`true`/`false`). Si devuelve verdadero, se evalúa la `expresionSiVerdadero` y si es falso se evalúa la expresión `expresionSiFalso`, devolviendo como resultado de toda la expresión el valor obtenido de la que corresponda de estas.

Es más o menos equivalente a esto:

```
if (expresionBool) 
  expresionSiVerdadero
else 
  expresionSiFalso
```

Con la ventaja que te devuelve un único valor que puedes asignar a una variable o usar como parte de una expresión más compleja.

Ejemplos:

```
  Saldo += Operacion == "Credito" ? Valor : Valor * -1;
  Mayor = Numero > Mayor ? Numero : Mayor;
```

## Tu error

Ahora si, veamos el error que estás cometiendo, que es que estás intentando hacer asignaciones dentro de las expresiones del operador, por ejemplo en esta línea:

```
tipoDato = true ? sentencia+= dato: sentencia+="'"+dato+"'";
```

Sospecho que lo que quieres hacer es algo como:

```
sentencia+= tipoDato ? dato : "'"+dato+"'";
```

Como ves, la variable `tipoDato` que ya es booleana, puede utilizarse sola en la expresión, no hace falta compararla. Si es verdadera, devolverá `dato` y si no, la concatenación entre `''` de `dato`.